# Remove all instances of class when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove all instances of a given class on the page when a button is clicked. The code works fine on its own, just not from within a click function. The code I have is:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("myClass");
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the handler is even being invoked?  Add the relevant HTML to your question.

Comment: This would not remove all instances of the class from a page.

Comment: tvanfosson - the handler is fine because if I use an alert, it is working.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML?

Comment: jrummell - it's just a fixed width div with an ID of myButton, e.g. <div id="myButton" style="width:100px;">Remove Styles</div>. The click event works fine with say an alert, just not with the remove class line.

Comment: is a button with `myButton` id really exist?

Comment: Ryan, it would not remove all elements with that class because it's running the selector `#wrapper`. What it really does is `remove all elements with the class that have the id wrapper, and/or are contained inside the element wrapper`.  If you want to remove everything change the selector to `.myClass`

Answer (score 3):

Just try:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $(".myClass").removeClass("myClass");
});
```

which should catch *every* element with that class anywhere on the page.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/27cFm/

Comment: This is one of the first things I tried. It doesn't do anything. this on its own works fine though:  $(".myClass").removeClass("myClass");

Comment: @Ryan bizarre - I can't think of any reason why it would work standalone but _not_ in an event handler.

Comment: jrummell - $('#myButton').click(function() {
    alert("hello");
}); this works so I would say yes

Comment: @Ryan I made a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/27cFm/  there must be something in the code you're _not_ showing us that's causing the fault.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#wrapper").removeClass("myClass");
```

will remove myClass class only from #wrapper element (element with id "wrapper") right? May you need something like:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $("#wrapper .myClass").removeClass("myClass");
});
```

First: match all the elements with myClass class inside wrapper, then remove their myClass class attribute

Please comment if I misunderstood the question thus I can fix the response

Answer (score 1):

To remove all instances of myClass on the page when a button is clicked, you can try:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    // this will select all elemets with 'myClass'
    var $target = $(".myClass");

    // this will remove 'myClass' from the selected elements
    $target.removeClass("myClass");

    // this will remove the selected elements from DOM
    // $target.remove();
});
```

Comment: Re-reading your question I got a doubt: did you actually mean to "remove the class from the elements on page" or to "remove the elements that are marked with the class from the page"?

Comment: Hi, @Ryan, I commented out the code that removed the elements from DOM. Does it solve your problem?